# How manually get a modified xml after use of transforms without XSLT?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, digital-signature, xml-signature

I have a signed document of the xml. There is the node Signature at down of document. This node has XPath's expressions which describe the sequence of actions from top to bottom. I want to get a modified xml perfoming a XPath's expression action step-by-step.

A part of the source xml:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.06" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <PmtInf>
    </PmtInf>
    <SplmtryData>
      <Envlp>
        <SngtrSt>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" id="Test1">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:*someCert*"/>
              <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <XPath xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">not(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature)</XPath>
                  </Transform>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <XPath xmlns:target_prefix="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.06">ancestor-or-self::target_prefix:Document</XPath>
                  </Transform>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <XPath xmlns:target_prefix="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.06">ancestor-or-self::target_prefix:CstmrCdtTrfInitn</XPath>
                  </Transform>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <XPath xmlns:target_prefix="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.06">ancestor-or-self::target_prefix:PmtInf[1]</XPath>
                  </Transform>
                </Transforms>
```

Result which i wait:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.06" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <PmtInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

How can i do this with the System.Security.Cryptography.Xml or a some library???

Comment: Could you explain the "without XSLT" in your title? A requirement to solve a problem without using a particular tool usually suggests some other constraint that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelKay I want to find a tool that will allow me to simply take the necessary xpath and use it on the xml document. I heard that there is something similar in java - xmlSec. In the dot net box, somehow these actions occur. and xslt is not flexible in this case.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I also have information about the algorithms used when signing. They are stored in Transform tags. Why can not I use it to simulate all the same actions that were performed in the dot net box when signing

Comment: I try to use:
var xpathNodes = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("XPath");
            transform.LoadInnerXml(xpathNodes);
            transform.LoadInput(xmlDoc);
            var nl = (XmlNodeList)transform.GetOutput();
But it doesn't work how i want

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: I would probably tackle this by writing an XSLT stylesheet to take your document as input and generate another XSLT stylesheet as output. Alternatively it could be done in XSLT 3.0 using xsl:evaluate. I'm not aware of any tool more specific to XML Security and signatures that would make the job easier.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I believe that the System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.CheckSignature method does not work correctly. The method internally somehow parses the XPath expressions, but I don’t know how, so I want to manually flex using the XPath expressions that I have in the Signature tag to display the necessary nodes.

Comment: @NickNick - can you please [edit] your question and share your a sample of code and XML that currently is not working, i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc, at the current moment i haven't a code because i look for a tool or library or framework which can help to me with my issue. I just have a xml (quote 1) and i want to get a modified xml (qoute 2) using transform (from quote 1) to mutate the xml.

Comment: i work with signed xml using the System.Security.Cryptography.Xml from .net box

Comment: @MichaelKay,  i want to ask: if i will have different values of nodes of Transformation->XPath then can i use some universal XSLT scheme????